# Xml string representation of expected result for Junit test

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing a Junit test in which the expected result is a XML string. What's the best way represent the expected string? Right now I have it as a stringBuilder and I do the following. I want to assert that the actual and expected are same. What would be the most efficient way to represent this expected string? Also I don't want anyone to alter the expected string so it should be final too.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    expected.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    expected.append("<n-relationship guid=\"IEEBFAD40BC5711DFAE41F5F92790F896\" control=\"add\">");
    expected.append("<n-relbase>ID17A8B10BC5711DFAE41F5F92790F896</n-relbase><n-reltype>IPLS</n-reltype>");
    expected.append("<ip.content><pub.no>1234567</pub.no>");
    expected.append("<event.date>2010-09-10</event.date><event.code>02394802323</event.code>");
    expected.append("<event.treatment>+</event.treatment><event.description>OPPOSITION DISMISSED</event.description>");
    expected.append("</ip.content></n-relpayload></n-relationship");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) XML does not belong inside java code. Put it in the same package (preferably in the src/main/resources folder if you use maven) and load it as a resource.

b) Don't do a string comparison with XML: do an XML structure comparison. [The canonicalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080242/xml-string-representation-of-expected-result-for-junit-test/4080311#4080311) is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is harder than it looks - string comparisons will certainly fail. This is because at least

- different representations for same entity (& apos;, etc.)
- different order of attributes
- different quotes
- whitespace

The simplest way is to canonicalise the XML in both the expected and test and compare those. All good XML tools should have a canonicalizer.

I have had to write a lot of XML machinery to support my Unit tests - admittedly they contain floating point numbers and I have to allow for rounding errors.

But comparing strings will certainly fail.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing 2 XML using their String representation is dangerous. Indeed, do you consider the following XML :

```
<foo>
  <bar>xxx</bar>
  <baz>yyy</baz>
</foo>
```

equals to:

```
<foo>
  <baz>yyy</baz>
  <bar>xxx</bar>
</foo>
```

?

If yes, then I suggest that you use [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to test your current XML with the expected one.

Regarding the expected XML, the best way is to store them as external files, and load them during your test (in a `@BeforeClass` snippet for example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the correct track -- define a string constant "EXPECTED_XML" and just assert off that.